# JS mexendo em variável que não tem que mexer

Tags: javascript, jquery, array

Fiz um código que agrupa alguns itens mais pertos em um só, pela posição `x` e `y`. O código está fazendo corretamente, mas estou enfrentando um problema. Na primeira vez que a função executa, faz todo processo normalmente. Quando clico em um botão pra executar novamente, ele deveria pegar os itens do array `PosicoesOriginal = [...]` e jogar em uma outra variavel para essa variavel ser modificada e não a `PosicoesOriginal`...

```
const PosicoesOriginal = [.....]; //Aqui tem todos os itens
function GeraPosicoesDistribuidores(){

       let grupos = [];

       //Aqui ele joga os itens dentro de outra variavel, pois não pode modificar o PosicoesOriginal

       let espelhoPosicoes = PosicoesOriginal;

       console.log(PosicoesOriginal);

       espelhoPosicoes.forEach(function(i, p){

        let toUp = i.y + distancia;
        let toDown = i.y - distancia;
        let toRight = i.x + distancia;
        let toLeft = i.x - distancia;
        let estado = i.estado;

          let gruposTemp = [];
          espelhoPosicoes.forEach(function(e, ps){

            if(between(e.y, toDown, toUp) && between(e.x, toLeft, toRight)){

              gruposTemp.push(e);
              espelhoPosicoes.splice(ps, 1);
            }
          });

          grupos.push(gruposTemp);
        });

        if(espelhoPosicoes != ''){

          espelhoPosicoes.forEach(function(e, p){
            let gruposTemp = [];

            gruposTemp.push(e);
            grupos.push(gruposTemp);
          });
        }

        console.log(PosicoesOriginal); //Verifico o que tem
        return grupos;
    }
```

No primeiro **console.log** ele exibe todos os dados corretamente, no último **console.log** ele exibe menos itens, mas o estranho é que não coloquei o `splice` para mexer na `PosicoesOriginal` e sim em `espelhoPosicoes`. Se eu retiro o `splice` ele exibe igual nos 2 console.log

Answer (score 0):

`PosicoesOriginal` e `espelhoPosicoes` referenciam o mesmo objeto, ou seja, quando `espelhoPosicoes` altera o objeto, as mudanças são refletidas em `PosicoesOriginal`. Caso seja necessário alterar o valor de um sem  alterar o valor outro deve-se copiar o objeto.
Como o objeto é um Array, pode-se fazer a copia da seguinte maneira:

```
    espelhoPosicoes = PosicoesOriginal.slice()
```

Veja a documentação de slice em [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)